# Why aggregate+sort is faster than find+sort in mongo?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework

I'm using mongoose in my project. When the number of documents in my collection becomes bigger, the method of find+sort becomes slower. So I use aggregate+$sort instead. I just wonder why?

Comment: `find` will do iteration internally and then `sort` so, it take bit more time then `aggregate+sort`.

Answer (score 3):

Without seeing your data and your query it is difficult to answer why aggregate+sort is faster than find+sort.

But below are the things that holds good on find and aggregate

- A well indexed(Indexing that suits your query) data will always yield faster results on your find query.
- The components of aggregation pipeline which you use on your aggregate query, more operations is directly proportional to more execution time.
- When you go for aggregation pipeline you can create new fields such as sum, avg and so on, which is not possible in a find.

see this thread for more info

[MongoDB {aggregation $match} vs {find} speed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28364319/mongodb-aggregation-match-vs-find-speed)