# MongoDB Aggregation V/S simple query performance?

Tags: mongodb, performance, aggregation-framework

I am reasking this question as i thought this question should be on seperate thread from  this one [in-mongodb-know-index-of-array-element-matched-with-in-operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41090280/in-mongodb-know-index-of-array-element-matched-with-in-operator/41109639).

I am using mongoDB and actually i was writing all of my queries using simple queries which are find, update etc. (No Aggregations). Now i read on many SO posts see this one for example [mongodb-aggregation-match-vs-find-speed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28364319/mongodb-aggregation-match-vs-find-speed). Now i thought about why increasing computation time on server because as if i will compute more then my server load will become more, so i tried to use aggregations and i thought i am going in right direction now. But later on my previous question [andreas-limoli](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3124885/andreas-limoli) told me about not using aggregations as it is slow and for using simple queries and computing on server. Now literally i am in a delimma about what should i use, i am working with mongoDB from a year now but i don't have any knowledge about its performance when data size increases so i completely don't know which one should i pick.

Also one more thing i didn't find on anywhere, if aggregation is slower than is it because of $lookup or not, because $lookup is the foremost thing i thought about using aggregation because otherwise i have to execute many queries serially and then compute on server which appears to me very poor in front of aggregation.

Also i read about 100MB restriction on mongodb aggregation when passing data from one pipeline to other, so how people handle that case efficiently and also if they turn on Disk usage then because Disk usage slow down everything than how people handle that case.

Also i fetched 30,000 sample collection and tried to run aggregation with $match and find query and i found that aggregation was little bit faster than find query which was aggregation took 180ms to execute where as find took 220 ms to execute.

Please help me out guys please it would be really helpful for me.

Comment: I'd like to figure this out too...

Comment: well quoting from mongoDB World "aggregation is new find" they have been doing improvements in aggregation performance since long. Just to clear find will always be faster than match aggregation provided indexes are apt. What does explain() showed in your case ?

Comment: Aggreagtion is to be used when you want to perform functions like sum, maximum, minimum, avg etc. Also If you want to join multiple collection based on a field. Find is supposed to be used as basic where clauses. Aggregation has a lot more to do than a simple find(). That could possibly be the reason.

Answer (score 3):

Aggregation framework in MongoDB is similar to join operations in SQL. Aggregation pipelines are generally resource intensive operations. So if in case your work is satisfied with simple queries, you should use that one at first place.

However, if it is absolute necessary then you can use aggregation pipelines in case you need to fetch the data from the multiple collections.

Answer (score 3):

Aggregation pipelines are costly queries. It might impact on your performance as an increasing data because of CPU memory. If you can achieve the with find query, go for it because Aggregation is costlier once DB data increases.