# Difference between sort with aggregation and sort with find

Tags: mongodb

Is there any difference between following two queries, please explain

```
db.grades.aggregate([{$sort: {type:1 score:1 } }])
```

and

```
db.grades.find().sort({type:1, score:1})
```

I got the same result when I run these queries, please explain functional and performance differences

Thanks

Comment: Have a look this. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28364319/mongodb-aggregation-match-vs-find-speed?answertab=votes#tab-top

Answer (score 1):

`sort()` applies to the documents that are being returned.

`$sort` applies to **all** of the element inside of such documents.