# Difference between db.find and db.aggregate in Mongo Nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I want to know is there any difference between the output from db.find and db.aggregate in MongoDB.

I am using Nodejs to query some data from Mongo DB, where the current implementation is:

```
Document.find(
       { userid: mongoose.Types.ObjectId(userId) },
       {
         '_id':1,
         'name':1,
         'size':1,
  })
```

but I want to calculate size on the go with the value in the DB, so I got to know I can not alter the value in find query, so I have to use aggregate:

```
 Document.aggregate([
      {$match:{userid: mongoose.Types.ObjectId(userId), isDeleted: deleted }},
      {$project:{
        '_id':1,
        'name':1,
         'size': {$size: "$followers"}
      }}
    ])
```

Now, both the queries give same result, I also checked the data type with typeof() both returns object.

But When the result from the aggregate function returns it throws some error on my other function which is using a map.

```
document = await Promise.all(document.map(async(doc) => {
      let followerData
     
      if (doc.size > 0) {
        const icon = await getIcon(doc.name)
        if (icon){
          followerData = {
            socialIcon: icon,
            name: name,
          }
        }
    
      }
      
      return { ...doc._doc, followerData }
    }))
```

Now, this function works with find but not working with aggregate, it only add the followerData and removed the existing data fetched from db. Don't know what is going here. Anyone could help me?

SCHEMA:

```
var socialSchema = new Schema({
  userid: {
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'users',
    required: true,
  },
  name: { type: String, max: 255 },
  followers: [
  {
  name: { type: String },
  handle: { type: String },
 },
 ],
  size: {
    type: Number,
    default: function() {
      return this.followers.length
    },
  }
})
```

Comment: Would you show your `mongoose` schemas/models?

Comment: What's the error that is thrown?

Comment: @rickhg12hs added schema

Comment: @RodrigoSasaki error is nothing, but when I pass the data to document.map the return result is only the followerData and the data from db is removed, but when I tried it with db.find query I get data from db + followerData after the map function.

Comment: Perhaps you could compare `console.log(doc)` within `map` for `find` and `aggregate`.

Comment: @rickhg12hs I tried that but the strange thing is that all the value is same in both the cases, hence I am confused what is happening exactly here

Comment: `aggregate` returns `._doc`?  See [Queries [`find`] vs. Aggregation](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/queries.html#versus-aggregation).

Comment: @rickhg12hs ohh goshh! both does not return ._doc but after your comment I tried to remove that and it works.. thank you so much for noticing

Comment: In principle `find` provides only `$match` and `$project` operators (see [Query and Projection Operators](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/v6.0/reference/operator/query/)) whereas `aggregate` provides much more: [Aggregation Pipeline Stages](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/v6.0/reference/operator/aggregation-pipeline/)

Answer (score 0):

The main purpose of the aggregation is to ease the query of a big number of entries and generate a low number of results that hold value to you.

You can also use multiple find queries, but remember that you can not create new fields with find queries. On the other hand, the $group stage allows you to define your new fields.

If your query is complex like adding a new field or summing up the fields or comparing the field etc you can use aggregation. It will take more time but do better results than find.

For more details, you can follow up this link [Aggregation vs Find](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28364319/mongodb-aggregation-match-vs-find-speed)